# Hot Reloading of changes in Pallet in substrate

Tags: substrate-node-template

While developing with substrate when we make changes in pallets and want to quickly test the changes have explicitly stop existing running node and build the node template (which obviously takes time) and again start the node which takes a lot of time due bootstrap, GRANDPA and all other rituals.

Do we have some existing solution which I'm not aware of just like other development framework provide `HOT RELOAD` capability so the developer experience is not hampered and these repetitive task which are avoidable can omitted.

Please let help me with if there are any existing solutions.

If not will raise a feature request and check for the feasibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't exists such a feature. However, given the upgradability of the runtime you could just rebuild your runtime and send a runtime upgrade. Be aware that you would also need to bump your `spec_version`. You could automate some of the work through some simple script.

You don't need to open a feature request for this, as this can be done through a script which can live completely separate to substrate.

Comment: How could I miss that. smart!!!!!

Comment: I am guessing the Substrate devs also make extensive use of tests with `cargo test -p pallet_name` - that is faster than spinning up a node

Comment: @RosaryBeads let me check and get back to you

Comment: Yes, but these are only unit tests. I mean for basic functionality you can write unit tests :)